# PostgreSQL Expression not evaluated properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sum

```
select ((x.am1998-x.am1999)/ ((x.am1998+x.am1999)/2))  as answer from
(select (sum(amount) FILTER(where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date)=1998)) as am1998,
(sum(amount) FILTER(where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date)=1999)) as am1999 from orders) x;



 number | order_date | sid | cust_id | amount 
--------+------------+-----+---------+--------
     10 | 1996-08-02 |   2 |       4 |    540
     20 | 1999-01-20 |   8 |       4 |   1800
     30 | 1995-07-14 |   1 |       9 |    460
     40 | 1998-01-29 |   2 |       7 |   2400
     50 | 1998-02-03 |   7 |       6 |    600
     60 | 1998-03-02 |   7 |       6 |    720
     70 | 1998-05-06 |   7 |       9 |    150
```

When I use expression ((x.am1998-x.am1999)/ ((x.am1998+x.am1999)/2))

But the output answer comes to zero? Why so?

But the individual answers
(x.am1998-x.am1999) ,(x.am1998+x.am1999)/2) if displayed are shown correctly?

Any help is highly appreciated/

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Answer (score 1):

That's integer division. Both operands to the division are (presumably!) integers, so Postgres returns an integer result. Typically, `3/4` is `0`, not `0.75`.

You can work around it by turning one of the operands to a decimal. For example:

```
(x.am1998 - x.am1999)/ ((x.am1998 + x.am1999) / 2.0)
```

Note: you tagged both Postgres and MySQL. The former does integer division, not the latter - so this has to be Postgres.